# Loop through files in folder, replace content and Save as new Name

Tags: batch-file

I need to loop through filed end with .edi in my folder, replace a character in the content and then save the file in another folder with "_updated"on the end.

e.g.

C:/Test/FileName.edi replace `'` in file with `^` and save the file into C:/Test/Output/FileName_Updated.edi

I've tried the following code and it works up until the saving the filename part, I've got confused somewhere, I don't usually write batch scripts:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (C:\Test\*.edi) do (


    set "input=C:\Test\"
    SET "output=C:\Test\Output\"

    for %%a in (%%f) do (
        set "output=%output%%%~na_update.%%~xa"
    )

    (for /f "delims=" %%i in (%%f) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:'=^!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )))>> %output%


)
```

Comment: You'll need delayed expansion also for `output`! Any what is the `for %%f` loop for, why not just using `%%~af` and `%%~xf` directly?

Comment: Please can you explain (maybe add your code to the above?) Apologies I'm more familiar with other languages

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with help from aschipfl

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\*.edi) do (

    SET "output=C:\Users\CHRW\Desktop\EDILocalTest\Output\"

     for %%a in (%%f) do (
        set "outputfile=!output!%%~na_update%%~xa"
    )

       (for /f "delims=" %%i in (%%f) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:'=^!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    ))>> !outputfile!

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (C:\Test\*.edi) do (


    set "input=C:\Test\"
    SET "output=C:\Test\Output\"

    (for /f "delims=" %%i in (%%f) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        rem setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:'=^!"
        echo(!line!
        rem endlocal
    )))>> "%output%%%~nf_update.%%~xf"


)
```

Since you were changing the value of `output` within the loop, the redirection should have been to `!output!` not `%output%` - the changed value of `output`, not the value of `output` at the time the *outer* `for` loop was parsed.

Since `%%f` contains a filename, there's no need to re-parse it.  Easier to construct the output filename in-line

Since `delayedexpansion` has been invoked at the start of the procedure, there's no need to re-invoke it and close the new invocation. I've REMmed-out those lines as it may be that you are presenting abbreviated code.